# variable defined field in Elasticsearch using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Here is my query in Elasticsearch,

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "default_field": "Comment",
            "query": "Comment1"
         }
     }
    }
 }
```

I need to change "Comment1" to a variable called comment.

Comment: OK... so what happened when you did that?

Answer (score 0):

It's now working.

```
comment=somecomment
{
     "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "default_field": "Comment",
            "query": 'Comment' + str(tweet['fields']['Comment']).lstrip('\'[u').rstrip(']\'')
         }
     }
    }
```